# How to set a HTML element ID on a material-ui component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a website built with Gatsby.js using the [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/).

Specific problem is this: I want to use the Google Tag Manager "Element Visibility" triggers. If some HTML element becomes visible, GTM should fire some GA tag.

Question is this: how can I specify the HTML ID for a material-ui component for GTM (or anything else) to find it?

First example:

```js
// ...react imports omitted...
import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

import Link from '~components/Link';
import ButtonSubmit from '~components/form-buttons/ButtonSubmit';
import Container from '~components/Container';

// ... all other imports are in-house code

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({ /* ...styles... */}));

const GuestUserSoftSaleSecondPopup = ({ which, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  // ...setup code omitted...

  return (
    <Box bgcolor="#474d5c" width="100%" py={4} className={classes.banner}>
      <Container>
        <Grid container direction="row" justify="space-between" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={1} md={3} lg={4}>
            <CloseIcon onClick={handleClose} size="large" className={classes.closeIcon} />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={7} md={5} lg={4}>
            <Link to="/subscribe" variant="h5" className={classes.linkStyle}>
              Become a member for full access
            </Link>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} className={classes.buttonPosition}>
            <Link to="/subscribe" underline="none" className={classes.linkStyle}>
              <ButtonSubmit type="button" fullWidth={false}>
                See my option
              </ButtonSubmit>
            </Link>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
};
// ...proptypes and `export` clause
```

Second example:

```js
// ...react imports omitted...
import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles';
import MuiDialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({ /* ...styles... */ }));

const Dialog = ({ children, background, backdrop, isOpen, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ background });
  return (
    <MuiDialog
      open={isOpen}
      maxWidth="sm"
      fullWidth
      disableBackdropClick
      disableEscapeKeyDown
      BackdropProps={{
        className: backdrop ? classes.backdropBM : classes.backdrop
      }}
      PaperProps={{
        className: classes.paper
      }}
      scroll="body"
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </MuiDialog>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please show the code of the element you want to put an ID on. Without knowing which component you are working with, it is difficult to help.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Added two examples of our custom components which I want to be findable by ID.

Comment: I believe many components have a `component` prop where you can pass in your custom component (like [`Grid`](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#props)) so you can probably pass in a custom component, which is just a `div` with whatever `id` you want?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher Indeed this is exactly the solution I am trying right now. Answer from Shimmy568 led me to this idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the API documentation for almost any of the Material-UI components, you will find at the end of the "Props" section a statement like the following example from [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#props):

> Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element (Modal).

This means that any props not explicitly recognized by this component will be passed along eventually to whatever HTML element is the outermost element rendered. So for most Material-UI components, in order to add an `id` property, you just specify it.

My example below (a modification of the [Simple Dialog demo](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#simple-dialogs)) includes three different ids: one on the `Dialog` element which will be placed on the outermost `div` of the `Modal`, one specified via the `PaperProps` which will go on the main `Paper` `div` of the visible content of the dialog, and one on the `Box` wrapped around the dialog content.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemAvatar from "@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import PersonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { blue } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

const emails = ["username@gmail.com", "user02@gmail.com"];
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: blue[100],
    color: blue[600]
  }
});

function SimpleDialog(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { onClose, selectedValue, open } = props;

  const handleClose = () => {
    onClose(selectedValue);
  };

  const handleListItemClick = value => {
    onClose(value);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
      open={open}
      PaperProps={{ id: "MyDialogPaperID" }}
      id="ThisIDWillBeOnTheModal"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Set backup account</DialogTitle>
      <Box id="MyBoxID">
        <List>
          {emails.map(email => (
            <ListItem
              button
              onClick={() => handleListItemClick(email)}
              key={email}
            >
              <ListItemAvatar>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                  <PersonIcon />
                </Avatar>
              </ListItemAvatar>
              <ListItemText primary={email} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Box>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

SimpleDialog.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  selectedValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default function SimpleDialogDemo() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(emails[1]);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = value => {
    setOpen(false);
    setSelectedValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1">Selected: {selectedValue}</Typography>
      <br />
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open simple dialog
      </Button>
      <SimpleDialog
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit id on Dialog, Paper, and Box]

Answer (score 2):

Material UI components don't let you set an id for them since the implementation inside should be a black box and may contain multiple html element. See if you can wrap the element in a div and put the id on that instead.

Another option would be to add a class (via the `classes` prop) to the element instead but I'm not sure if Google Tag Manager can use those instead of ids.

Comment: Oh! Wrapper div with an ID is an idea! Crude but may work. `classes`, I'm afraid, will not work because the building toolchain autoprefixes all the classes to make them unique for all the components on the page, so I can't predict the final name in the HTML.

Comment: @hijarian Not sure but the prefixing is possibly done just for css stuff. I have a feeling the classes thing may still work. May be worth a shot if a wrapper div is too crude for your taste. Can't be 100% sure though

Comment: By the way, instead of adding a wrapper I can add a _marker_ element, just an empty `div` with the ID anywhere inside the component. It's not that I actually care that the _popup_ has the ID, I want some element with that ID to appear on the page together with the popup...

Comment: Some components (like the [Radio button](https://material-ui.com/api/radio/#props) can have user-defined `id`)